# StringFormat in wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to combine static text AND binding in one TextBlock? Because StringFormat  don't work in windows phone 7.
I try

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding strAudioArtistName, StringFormat=StaticText: {0}}"/>
```

but don't work....

Thank

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695057/formatting-a-date-in-xaml-on-wp7#4695125

Answer (score 7):

Actually if you can change your viewmodel and do the formatting in a property you will get much better performance than relying on an IValueConverter.

I use a pattern along these lines to still give me property change notifications

```
string _value;
public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); NotifyPropertyChanged("ValueFormatted"); } }
public string ValueFormatted { get { return "Static Text: " + _value; } }
```

Comment: This is true; despite my answer this is what I've been moving to as well.  It's also easier to debug.

Comment: I would agree with @jeff here. Much cleaner solution. +1

Answer (score 5):

`WP7` uses `Silverlight 3`. So, you don't get `StringFormat`. Use `IValueConverter` instead.