# ListBox template, hiding elements

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I have a listbox template showing an image and three textboxes. You will see how are they distributed in the code below. My problem is that some items won't have an image and I want the text to fill the whole row in that case.
I've tried not to use a grid, to use a canvas, but I don't know why, when using a canvas inside a listbox, nothing is shown. I don't know if this is easy to accomplish. Here's the code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="itemList" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="listBoxSetmana_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="480">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="17" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFFF003F" Padding="1">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listImage" Width="36" Height="36" Source="{Binding thumbnail}" />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Padding="0 0 25 0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="title" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding title}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" />
                <TextBlock Padding="0 0 25 0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="published" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding published}" FontSize="13" />
                <TextBlock Padding="0 0 25 0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="subtitle" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding subtitle}" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{Binding id}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can't see where you're using `Canvas` in the code that you've supplied, but the **Padding** values should be comma-separated, not space: `Padding="0,0,25,0"`

Comment: thanks for pointing out the commas lack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to bind this together.

One way is:

- add some Padding to the Border
- bind the Visibility of the Border to the thumbnail Property using an appropriate ValueConverter
- change the width of Column 0 from "60" to "Auto" - then it will disappear when the image is Collapsed.

Comment: I've found this example on how using converters (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695057/formatting-a-date-in-xaml-on-wp7), but my xaml doesn't recognise the word namespace. How can I define the converter as a resource?

Comment: you need to define your namespace - in the first declaration in your xaml, add something like xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters" that will allow you to use "mynamespace:MyConverter" to include your converter

Comment: Fantastic! thank you for your help. I think I need a good manual on silverlight