# wp7 Date Formatting during Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I tried following the following example with no luck:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

I also tried to follow this as well:

[Formatting a date in XAML on WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695057/formatting-a-date-in-xaml-on-wp7)

I can't get it to work.  When I try to add a reference such as:

```
<namespace:dateTimeConverter x:Key="MyDateTimeToStringConverter"/>
```

**or**

```
<src:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any assistance is appreciated!

**Here is my class code:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace OilChangeApplication
{

    public class dateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
            return date.ToShortDateString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string strValue = value as string;
            DateTime resultDateTime;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime))
            {
                return resultDateTime;
            }
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

}
```

**Here is my windows phone form xaml:**

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="OilChangeApplication.historyInfo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.Resources>

        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



            <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Change your Oil Application 2.0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="history" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>



        <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">


                <ListBox Height="601" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-3,2,0,0" Name="lbHistory" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" ItemsSource="{Binding historyItemsCollection}">

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="DataTemplateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,10">*</TextBlock>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding VehicleName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <!--<TextBlock x:Name="ocDate" Text="{Binding OilChangedDate}"></TextBlock>-->
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OilChangedDate, Converter={StaticResource dateTimeConverter},ConverterParameter=\{0:M\}}" />
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ocOdometer" Text="{Binding OilChangedOdometer}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>


    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/check.png" Text="save" x:Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/cancel.png" Text="cancel" x:Name="btnCancel" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had a bit of trouble with converters and found an easy work around is to have another property on the class you are binding called something along the lines of DisplayDate.

For example if you are binding OilChangedDate you could add this property to the class you bind:

```
public string OilChangedDisplayDate
{
    get { return OilChangedDate.ToShortDateString(); }
}
```

Then bind this property instead of the date directly.

Comment: Thank you.  I got so hung up with this converter that this solution was too easy for me to see :) - Thanks!